# php syntax difference unix vs windows

Tags: php, linux, syntax

I made a project in PHP in windows.
It was something like

```
$item = [3, 5, 6];
```

It works splendid in windows.
When i use the same code in linux, i get an error, `unexpected [`

So i try

```
$item = array(3, 5, 6);
```

Which is working.
Now my project is screwed because i developed in windows but actually need to run on linux.
Why is it not behaving the same on both OS and are there any other potential triping wires when it comes to coding PHP ?

- thanks

Comment: check the interpreter **version**: the `[ ]` syntax was introduced in 5.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is obviously no difference in syntax.

The PHP version on Linux must be older than PHP 5.4 since only since that version, the short array definer was introduced.

Old versions are problematic and you might not be able to run any newer libraries since most of them use `[]` to initialize arrays.

Nowadays, it's expected for you to run PHP 5.6 to have all the features that various libraries might need.